# Why we are checking for a value if we are already checking for length

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am confused that why is this happening I am following along a code along and in there the instructor used

```
<% if(error && error.length > 0) {%> 
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><%= error %> </div>
<% } %>
<% if(success && success.length > 0) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><%= success %> </div>
<% } %>
```

I am not getting what is the point checking in error and success when we are already checking their length

Comment: If `success` is null or undefined, then trying to `.length` off of it would throw an Error

Comment: It's the other way round: you have to check whether `success` "exists" before accessing its `.length` property

Comment: It is to avoid a runtime error. Specifically it is to avoid the error of cannot access the value "length" of undefined. So `if (success)` checks that is is not undefined or null (or an empty string or the number zero) then `&&` shorts-circuits, that is, if the first part is false (if `success` is undefined) then it does not evaluate the second part. Finally once we know that success exists we can safely evaluate `success.length > 0`

Comment: If you try to obtain the length of an `undefined` variable or `null` variable, your code would throw an exception - this helps you prevent this exception

Comment: Empty string is falsy though, so I'm not sure why you need the `.length` at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `error` and `success` may be null, therefore, you would get an error of accessing property `length` of `undefined` or `null`

Answer (score 1):

Because `error` and `success` can be `undefined` or `null` and there won't be a `length` on them and if you check for length you will get an error 
you can use optional chaining instead, like this:

```
<% if(error?.length) {%> 
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><%= error %> </div>
<% } %>
<% if(success?.length) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><%= success %> </div>
<% } %>
```